# Fitting a distribution. How

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, fitting

First of all, i am not good at this. i need to know what distribution fits in this dataset. i though it could be a poisson due to the characteristics of the data. the data talks about forest fires.

This is the frequency table:

[image]

i used goodfit.

adpo <- goodfit(tor$RIsk, type = 'poisson',  method = 'MinChisq')

and then i get:

[image]

i don't know why it created count 0.

summary(adpo)

Goodness-of-fit test for poisson distribution

```
         X^2 df     P(> X^2)
  Pearson 106.6333  4 3.800189e-22
```

[image]

it is not a poisson. so, how do i know which distribution the dataset fit?

Comment: your values are truncated at 1.. is there a reason for this? Otherwise you will never find a suitable distribution for this kind of count / discrete data

Comment: By definition, any Poisson distribution assigns positive probability to a count of $0.$  Could you explain why you're trying to fit a distribution to these data?